# How does javascript recognise objects

Tags: javascript, html, oop, parsing, casting

I'm trying to test something which I might later use in a more complex application however I'm struggling to find why this following code is not working. I'm not that familiar with javascript however I have noticed that there is no such thing as casting?

I have the following piece of code which in Java if casted should work however in this following script, it doesn't. To be more specific the following error gets returned:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'putImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided. test.html:16
window.onload
```

Here is the code

```
        <script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var imageObject = ctx.getImageData(0,0,100,200);
        var stringed = JSON.stringify(imageObject);

        var nowShouldBeImage = JSON.parse(stringed);
        ctx.putImageData(nowShouldBeImage,0,0);
    }

    </script>
```

My question is why is it that the object after being parsed is not getting recognised correctly? What am I missing here? And how would I tackle the lack of this functionality in javascript? ( Maybe not lack of functionality but rather difference from Java)

Comment: What IDE are you running this in?

Comment: No ide. I wrote this in sublime and ran in in google chrome

Comment: Probably `nowShouldBeImage` is not `ImageData`, but just an array or something. There is no "casting"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON object parses files into simple structures.
You're basically getting an array of channel values back, I believe.

`.putImageData` doesn't work with arrays, but rather with ImageData objects (which may behave like arrays, but are not).

You've got multiple solutions, here, if what you're interested in is sending something to / loading something from the server.

If you want to use XHR, then you can use base64 to go back and forth.

```
var canvas     = getMyCanvas(),
    ctx        = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    encImgData = canvas.toDataURL();

var img = new Image();
img.src = encImgData;

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

If you want to go through and manually edit that image's pixel-range thereafter, draw it to an offscreen canvas, `.getImageData()` to match the width and height of the image you cared about, edit the pixels, and `.putImageData()` using the edited object.

But `JSON` isn't going to marshal things into specific types for you.
It takes simple data structures, puts them in strings, and outputs those structures into other simple structures.

You *can* also write a node-modifying function which will be called as each node in the structure is being rebuilt.
If you specifically want to write a function which checks if the node is an array and it's filled with what you assume are per-channel values, and then use `ctx.createImageData`, and manually loop through and fill each channel of each pixel with the array value, and then return the constructed ImageData object, you can do that, too, I suppose.  But that's not going to do you any favours regarding speed.

Comment: How is `encImgData` a function?

Comment: @Bergi whoops.  It was a function, because thanks to my newborn, my brain no longer does.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @Norguard should the toDataURL() be already defined or should I create it?

Comment: @Bula ...that's one more gap in my braining.  It's actually `canvas.toDataURL()`, not `ctx.toDataURL()`.  I'll fix that, now.

Comment: @Norguard ah don't worry. Thanks for such a quick, informative and very detailed answer. I had no idea that JSON stringify was not a good  decision here

Comment: @Bula for future reference, JSON's `.stringify` will basically do key-value structuring, for over-the-wire transfer. If the value is a function, discard the property, if the value is a string, escape quotes, if otherwise scalar, copy directly, if an object with a unique `toString` use that, else, iterate the properties, if it's an array, make an array iterate through the contents and apply the previous logic. This isn't an exact outline of the algorithm, but should illustrate why it does no marshaling, without passing it a per-node operation on `.parse`.

Comment: Before even looking at NodeJS, I'd suggest becoming very familiar with the JS way of doing things. Personally, I find Node much more pleasant (as the DOM is completely absent, and you can break out the fancy new EcmaScript 6 features), but in-browser JS is a very particular animal that needs respect, lest it bite.

Comment: @Norguard as you mentioned in this post I tried using the base64 encoding mechanism. Here is some code which apparently does not work:  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   var image = ctx.getImageData(0,0,100,200);
   var tobe = window.btoa(image);
   var tonotbe = window.atob(tobe);
   ctx.putImageData(tonotbe,0,0);

Comment: Am I missing something in this enconding? Does this encoding work only with strings?

Comment: @Bula `atob` and `btoa` only work on strings (or coerce to string, using `.toString`). `canvas.toDataURL` ***provides*** a Base64-encoded image.

Comment: @Bula `var encImgData = canvas.toDataURL();` will return a string like `"data:image/png;base64,***data here***"`. This string can be used as an image source, or as a CSS background image, et cetera. Don't try to marshal it. Just use it as the source for an image, paint that image to the canvas, using `ctx.drawImage`.

Comment: @Norguard How can I accept your answer again. I'm struggling to find a solution for this app that I'm trying to do for weeks. My bounties contain a question to how I should go around this. Please do claim the reputation you deserve

Answer (score 0):

1. **Java ≠ Javascript**, not use javascript as java.
2. this step seems useless:

   ```
   var stringed = JSON.stringify(imageObject); //object to string
   var nowShouldBeImage = JSON.parse(stringed); //same string to JSON?!?! nothing change... why?!!?
   ```
3. remove the useless step:

   ```
   var imageObject = ctx.getImageData(0,0,100,200);
   //var stringed = JSON.stringify(imageObject); remove this two line
   //var nowShouldBeImage = JSON.parse(stringed);
   ctx.putImageData(imageObject,0,0);
   ```

The object `nowShouldBeImage` isn't the same of `imageObject` because inside of this object there are some properties that are particular because are the result of `getImageData()` that after `JSON.stringify` are lost (`nowShouldBeImage` is an instance of **Object**, `imageObject` is an instance of **ImageData**)

Comment: 1) I did not make that missconception 2) As quoted from the post " I might later use in a more complex application". To give you an example a nodejs server. 3) check my 2)

Comment: My bad, I suck... I see you have find the answer... Enjoy. ;)

Comment: Don't worry. I probably should've went into more in depth about my real purpose. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing binary data with JSON. If you really need to do that, try encoding the ImageData object from getImageData() as base64 first.